# How do I either: import all of the js files into html or figure out which js files I need to get collapse from bootstrap to work?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I installed bootstrap with npm and now I have a bunch of .js files but there is no "master" js file that I can import into html, unlike the css file that does have a master .css file.

I was unable to get the collapse to work without a cdn with

```
<script src="./node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/collapse.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/button.js"></script>
```

But It did work with:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This is my collapse menu:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="col col-sm-2">
            <a class="" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#started" role="button">Getting Started</a>
            <div id="started" class="collapse">Hi</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-md-8">

        </div>
        <div class="col col-lg-2"></div>
    </div>
```

I'd prefer not to use the cdn because I'm already using the node_modules from the css and sass. Am I missing scripts to import? Or is there a way to easily import all of the scripts without manually doing it?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap#whats-included

Comment: I tried using `npm install bootstrap` and the downloading the files directly, and I don't see `bootstrap.min.js` files. Instead I see components js files like `button.js`, `dropdown.js`,`collapse.js`.

Comment: Well in that case maybe something went wrong with the download. The docs explicitly states a `bootstrap.min.js` file in `dist/js` directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bootstrap.min.js file thanks to ISAE.
I downloaded the bootstrap file here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap#whats-included and went into `bootstrap/dist/js/` which has all of the master bootstrap files.

You can also use `npm install bootstrap` and the pathway is very similar: `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/`